# Create PDF document from HTML using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, pdf

I want to create a PDF document from HTML in JavaScript. I tried using the library `jsPDF` but all the HTML formatting are not supported in it. Is there any other library that I can use to create the PDF?

Comment: use pdf.js http://mozilla.github.com/pdf.js/web/viewer.html

Comment: i want to pass a html content and produce a resulting pdf from it.Is it possible using pdf.js.I was only able to render a pdf document to a html page using it.

Comment: yes yes you can create a new pdf using pdf.js , please read their documentation

Comment: http://bytescout.com/products/developer/pdfgeneratorsdkjs/create_pdf_invoice_javascript.html

Comment: was there ever a answer to this question?

Answer (score 3):

I've just written a library called jsPDF (Give you the link below) which generates PDFs using Javascript alone. It's still very young, and I'll be adding features and bug fixes soon. Also got a few ideas for workarounds in browsers that do not support Data URIs. It's licensed under a liberal MIT license.

I came across this question before I started writing it and thought I'd come back and let you know :)

http://code.google.com/p/jspdf/

http://hayageek.com/generate-pdf-with-javascript/  //Try this link with step by step process

Answer (score 1):

You can create the html page as you like to have PDF then from javascript you can call print function of the browser which eventually exports a webpage to a pdf or in printable form

Answer (score 1):

Consider installing [gitbook-pdf](https://github.com/GitbookIO/gitbook-pdf)
`gitbook-pdf` uses `PhantomJS` and `rasterize.js` to build `PDF` files from `HTML`

You would require [NodeJS](http://nodejs.org) and NPM

After installing run commands:

`gitbook-pdf --format A4 generate index.html index.pdf`

> *A4* is the default paper format..there are other options too! check it out
>
> *index.html* is your main HTML file
>
> *index.pdf* is your final product

Hope that helps!