# How to generate a PDF out of a rendered HTML element?

Tags: javascript, dom, pdf, frameworks, pdf-generation

Is there a way to generate a PDF file in JavaScript out of a given rendered and styled element of a webpage and its content? Is there already a library for this?

Comment: Did you see this? http://stackoverflow.com/q/14770719/231316

Comment: See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23350531/405117)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There is a library called [jsPDF](https://github.com/MrRio/jsPDF/). It provides basic functionality to create PDF documents. It even comes with a plugin to add elements from basic HTML.

Comment: @Toolkit It's the best I'm aware of. If you found a better solution, please let me know. For now I'll stick with providing a print style cheet that hides everything else and use the browser's print to PDF functionality.

Comment: but the question was about  "styled element". There is dompdf but it requires PHP

Comment: @Toolkit Right, there a couple of server-side solutions for that. The challenge is to get it done on the client-side. By the way, it was me who asked the question.

Comment: I know this is your question, but the answer doesn't answers the question, because jsPDF ignores styles

Comment: @Toolkit I agree, it's not a complete answer to the question. Fair enough.

Answer (score -1):

I've never put it to use, but could https://github.com/thebluber/htmlToPdf be what you're looking for?