# Creating pdf file using native js?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, pdf, pdf-generation, docx

A have a project on angularjs and I need to create and download a document for print(no needed to save it on server). It can be .docx, but .pdf is preferable(so simple user won't able to change file). So, I know that there is a framework called PHPWord, but I don't like php at all. And there is another framework called docx.js(but it jquery required).

There is one more problem that I need to add values of variables to the docx template(which located on server, so admin can change it, of course he won't touch variables in this file) and then download fulfilled pdf document. It is not necessary to use docx template, nevertheless this variant is preferable.

Can you give me some recommendation in which way I need to look? Maybe you know some good framework based on native JS?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Create PDF document from HTML using JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14770719/create-pdf-document-from-html-using-javascript)

Comment: There's also https://github.com/open-xml-templating/docxtemplater which allows you to generate docx from a template (no PDF however)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't personally used this, but it looks like a contender.

It runs atop Node, so you can leverage your JavaScript skills.

http://pdfkit.org/
https://github.com/devongovett/pdfkit

Answer (score 0):

https://bytescout.com/products/developer/pdfgeneratorsdkjs/create-pdf-tutorial-for-javascript.html   please you put a plus. dont forget

Comment: Thanks! But I can't create pdf using docx template using this library, is it so?